# Godot: What options are there for removing the filtering or anti-aliasing from text

Tags: text, antialiasing, godot, pixel-art

If I were to start making a pixel-art game with the Godot engine, what options do I have for removing the filtering or anti-aliasing from text?

EDIT:

I want to know how to remove the AA from rendered text in a label node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling anti-aliasing in DynamicFont isn't supported in Godot 3.0, but it's possible in 3.1 beta (which also makes it possible to tweak font hinting).

To do so, you need to create a DynamicFont as usual, load a TTF or OTF file into its Font Data property, edit the Font Data resource, set the desired anti-aliasing/hinting settings then save the font data resource as a `.tres` file. (Otherwise, those settings won't be preserved when you exit the editor or launch the project.)

Answer (score 3):

You can customize your image import setting in godot 3.0+. Here is how from the Godot documentation :

[Godot Docs 3.0+ : Importing Images](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/workflow/assets/importing_images.html?highlight=Import%20image)

In the basic UI, when you select an image you can change tab to the import settings :

[image]

*(Taken from the doc)*

Here you can change several options to customize how your images are imported into Godot.

For pixel art, you can disable **Filter** and **Mimaps** for example.

PS : This solution works for Godot 3.0+, for Godot 2.1+ you can go to the corresponding documentation : [Godot Docs 2.1+ : Managing image files](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/2.1/learning/workflow/assets/managing_image_files.html?highlight=image%20import). As you are stating you want to start a new game, it is recommended to use the latest (3.0+) version of Godot.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know about text rendering.